# Need help picking a datamining/neural-network API

Tags: java, neural-network, data-mining

I'm planning on building a feature for an e-commerce platform I developed in Java to display related products in much the same way Amazon does. There are a few different metrics for relating products that I want to explore.

- Purchase history (purchased at the same time)
- Related by family/type (similar product classifications)
- Intentionally related (boosting results; "Buy this!")

While I would probably be able to develop my own datamining library, it wouldn't be very portable and I dare say it wouldn't be very good either.

There are several packages out there for doing this sort of thing but I don't feel like I am in a position to evaluate which package or solution would work best for me. Any input anecdotal or from personal experience would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I've tagged this as Neural networking because of a python talk I was at where a neural-like-network was used for datamining, I'm not convinced a neural network is the best choice for this job.

Comment: Collaborative filtering seems like a better approach to your problem than neural networks since you probably don't have a consistent training set with an obvious cost function. Mahout is well supported and based on Hadoop, which is THE Java map-reduce framework.  I don't have experience with it, but thought I'd try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster, you're probably right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Mahout](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/)

Comment: I've had a look at it, but I don't know how it compares to all the other platforms out there and if it will satisfy what I am looking for, that's really the crux of the problem here.

Without spending significant time or effort to evaluate each and every option, its impossible to make a rational choice. 

Do you have any experience with Mahout or a reason for suggesting it?

Comment: I believe what you want is a notion of item-item similarity. Mahout provides a fairly simple framework for this inside of its item-based recommender framework. Look at implementations of its `ItemSimilarity` interface. That and related code should do the essence of what you need. I'd follow up as `user@mahout.apache.org`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some artificial algorithm techniques used for data mining, such as [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) or [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm). These algorithm does classification. Other techniques such as ant clustering, neural networks or genetic algorithms are used for classification purposes in data mining.

As far as algorithms, I don't know much but ID3/C4.5 can be easily programmed.

Hope this helps.